# How to add columns names to a DF from a File

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dataframe without the colums names. It has more than 650 columns names and I have these column names in a separate file. My question is how to attach columns names to the dataframe from a separate file. Thanks in advance.Below is the code that I'm trying. Please help.( Columns_Names is the name of the file which has all 650 variable names separated by comma and each variable name is in quotation marks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change #1** - it seems each line has multiple column names. In that case, you should be using `list.extend` -

```
column_names.extend(line.strip().split(','))
```

Which grows the original list. `append` would insert a list into the list, which isn't what you need. Here's a little example -

```
>>> c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c.extend([4, 5, 6])
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Contrast this with -

```
>>> c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c.append([4, 5, 6])
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

---

**Change #2** - you can use the `names` attribute in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and pass `column_names` to it -

> `names` : array-like, default `None`
>   List of column names to use. If file
>   contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass `header=None`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\x01", header=None, names=column_names, nrows=100)
```